# ESLint not resolving absolute file path for extends

Tags: javascript, configuration, path, eslint

I'm attempting to get a local `eslintrc` (in my project root) to extend my global `eslintrc` (located at `~/.eslintrc`).

Here's the local `eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "~/.eslintrc"
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting when running `eslint foo.js`:

```
Cannot read config file: /Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/~/.eslintrc
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/~/.eslintrc'
Referenced from: /Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/.eslintrc
Error: Cannot read config file: /Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/~/.eslintrc
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/~/.eslintrc'
Referenced from: /Users/cbickel1/dev/learning/webpack-demo/.eslintrc
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
    at readFile (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:70:24)
    at loadLegacyConfigFile (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:142:44)
    at loadConfigFile (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:222:22)
    at load (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:505:18)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:391:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:362:28)
    at Object.load (/Users/cbickel1/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:536:22)
```

Looks like ESLint isn't correctly resolving the path given as absolute. What should I do?

Comment: change from `~/.eslintrc` to `./.eslintrc` and try

Comment: Doesn't work, just creates a circular reference.

Comment: Check if the file actually exists? `cat ~/.eslintrc`

Answer (score 3):

ESLint as of release v4.7.0 does not support *project root*.

Looking at the source, you either need to provide an *absolute* or *relative* path from the `.eslintrc` file.

Source: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v4.7.0/lib/config/config-file.js#L413

## Examples

### Absolute (Windows)

```
{
    "extends": "c:/git/project/.eslintrc"
}
```

### Absolute (Mac/Linux)

```
{
    "extends": "/Users/username/git/project/.eslintrc"
}
```

### Relative

```
{
    "extends": "../../../.eslintrc"
}
```